# Preparing report using laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel

In table A, there is an order number which acts as a primary key, let's call it booking no. In table B, there are many items in the same booking no. Now, I want to sum the qty and cost in table B which has the same booking no. How to write the correct query for this?

I am not sure where should I put the sum clause.

```
  $table = DB::table('table_a')
            ->join('table_b', 'table_a.book', '=', 'table_b.book')
            ->select('*')
            ->groupBy('book')
            ->get();
```

so the final result should be like this:

```
<table>
<thead >
<tr>
<th >Booking No.</th>
<th >Cost.</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>a88</td>
<td>$89</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

note that there may be 5 items contained in a single booking no, given its quantity and cost per items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$tables = DB::table('tableB')
          ->join('tableA','tableB.book_no' ,'=','tableA.book_no')
          ->select( 'tableA.*' , 'tableB.*', DB::raw('SUM(tableB.quantity) as qty, SUM(tableB.cost) as cost')
          ->groupBy('tableB.book_no')
          ->get();
```

In blade access it Like:

```
 @foreach($tables as $table)
 <td>$table->qty</td>
 <td>$table->cost</td>
 @endforeach
```